# Adding math operator beside \cline

Tags: math-mode, equations

### Update:

Here's what I meant. This was created in spreadsheet for demo purpose only. I just don't know how to achieve this using `LaTeX`.

[image: sample image]

...and here's my `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{Item A} &= 750 \\
\text{Item B} &= 500 \\
\text{Item C} &= 1,500\\
\cline{2-1}
\text{Total} &= 2,750 \\
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

I need to add a `+` sign on the right side. I also need the numbers to be right-aligned like in sample image above. I've read about this somewhere online but forget the link/url.

---

### Original question:

How to add math operator, i.e. `(+)` beside `\cline` in an equation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &= 2\\
b &= 3 \\
\cline{1-2}
c &= 5 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use an `align*` environment. The `array` environment provides far more flexibility.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for `\text` macro
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{r@{}r}
   & a = 2\\
   & b = 3 \\
+\,& \text{--{}--{}--{}--{}--{}}\\
   & c = 5 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Here's how I would address your follow-up formatting query.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{r C r @{\;} C}
\text{Item A} &=&   750 \\
\text{Item B} &=&   500 \\
\text{Item C} &=& 1,500 \\
& & \text{--{}--{}--{}--{}--{}} & + \\
\textbf{Total}  &=& \text{\fontseries{b}\selectfont 2{,}750} \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just updated my question. tks.

Comment: @guest_5758 - I've posted an addendum to my answer.

Comment: The addendum version works great! I just didn't expect the code would be that long. I thought it would be as simple as using `\cline` and `+` or something like that.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `tabular`, with some tricks for making the spaces correct:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}>{${}}c<{{}$}@{}r@{}l@{}}
\text{Item A} &=& 750 \\
\text{Item B} &=& 500 \\
\text{Item C} &=& 1,500\\
\cline{3-3}
&&&\raisebox{1.4ex}[0pt][0pt]{$\;+$}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
\bfseries\text{Total} &=& \fontseries{b}\selectfont 2,750 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico Of course!